# Jackson json deserialization mapping structure elasticsearch

Tags: jackson

I need to parse a json file like this:
This is a sample mapping file for a collection of my elasticsearch engine server.

```
{
    "mappings":
    {
            "documents" :
            {
                    "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
                    "properties" :
                    {
                            "user_id" :
                            {
                                    "type" : "string",
                                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                                    "store": "no"
                            },
                            "mime_type" :
                            {
                                    "type" : "string",
                                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                                    "store": "no"
                            },
                            "source" :
                            {
                                    "type" : "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                                    "store": "no"
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

As you could be figuring out the schema is like that:

```
{
  "mapping":
  {
     "**collection_name**":
     {
       ...,
       "properties":
       {
         "**property_name_1**":
         {
            "type": "string|int|date...",
            ...
         },
         "**property_name_2**":
         {
            "type": "string|int|date...",
            ...
         },
         ...
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

And I would need to map this json to something like these classes:

```
public class Mapping {

    private String collection;
    private List<Property> properties;

    public Mapping()
    {
        this.collection = null;
        this.properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
    }
    ...

 }

 public class Property
 {
    private String property;
    private String type;
}
```

I've no idea how to do it with jackson.
Could you help me please? Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it with jackson:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode rootNode;
    try {
        rootNode = mapper.readValue(jsonText, JsonNode.class);
        JsonNode mappingsNode = rootNode.get("mappings");
        String collectionName = mappingsNode.getFieldNames().next();
        JsonNode collectionNode = mappingsNode.get(collectionName);
        JsonNode propertiesNode = collectionNode.get("properties");
        Iterator<JsonNode> elements = propertiesNode.getElements();
        while (elements.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode propertyNode = (JsonNode) elements.next();
            // get properties one by one

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("error while reading value", e);
    }
```

Code is not completed by it presents the idea. Tested with jackson 1.8.0